# Geometrical interpretation $\left(\left| \frac{4i-3}{3i-z} \right| > 1\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to ask you about a geometrical interpretation (2D) of this example:

$  \left| \frac{4i-3}{3i-z} \right| > 1 $

The easiest form I got:

$ \frac{5}{\left|3 i-z\right| } > 1$

But how to draw this set on the plane?

I've run the query on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5B5%2F%28abs%283%20i-z%29%5D%20)

[Image from Wolfram Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN0hp.gif)

Is it  $y(1, +\infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{5}{\left|3 i-z\right| } > 1$$ or,
$$ 5>\left|3 i-z\right|$$ or, 
$$ 5>\left|z-3 i\right|$$ or,
$$ \left|z-3 i\right|<5$$ which is the equation of a **circular surface** (not just a circle) with center at $(0,3)$ and radius $5$. 
On the Argand plane,this will represent a circular region.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way to draw it in Wolfram Alpha? How did you know about the center point? Is it something like $z - z_o = z - (3i)$?

Comment: Yes, you are bang on. The equation for a circle with center $z_0$ and radius $r$ is $z-z_0 = r$

Comment: Aniket, by the way... Should I exclude the center point from the region?

Comment: @terry_8 No. The center point should be included for the inequality holds true for all points within the circle. However you should exclude the circumference as the inequality has no equality condition i.e. $|z-3i| \not = 5$

Comment: Ok, thank you. Dotted line for the boundary should be fine?

Comment: Yup. that will be fine.

Comment: Aniket, excuse me for being annoying but isn't the radius $5$?

Comment: Corrections are always welcome. Thank you